Pasar datos via POST con Async/Await
Tengo un problema al enviar datos via POST usando Async/Await, ya que el controlador no me recibe el parámetro que le paso y me bota error.
Esta es mi función async/await:
    async function request(pos) {
        
        const response = await fetch("controller/mensajes.php",{
            
            method: "POST",
            headers:{
              "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "load": pos
            })
        });
        
        const data = await response.json();
        
        return data;
        
    }

Aquí hago la llamada y muestro por consola lo que me regresa:
    const respuesta = request(load);
    console.log(respuesta);

Me bota un error porque no llega al controlador el parametro "load"
Alguna sugerencia, por favor?

A qué le llamas "el controlador"? Al script de PHP? Si no llega allí, sugiero que vayas por pasos y veas qué le estás enviando en el body primero. Un console.log() con el valor devuelto por stringify sería de ayuda.

@jachguate Sí, el controlador es un script en PHP donde valido con un isset($_POST['load']) si existe dicho parámetro, de lo contrario me arroje error y eso es lo que está haciendo, arrojándome error.

¿Qué se imprime en la consola?

Nota:
No mostraste los resultados console.log de cada variable, por ejemplo pos, así está complicado saber cómo proceder. Tampoco mostraste cuál error es el que te muestra. Sugiero editar la pregunta agregando los datos correctos.

Probablemente request sea una palabra reservada, lo que impediría declararla, los nombres de las funciones tendrían que estar en español para no confundirlas con el lenguaje de programación. Los nombres de las variables, también en español.
En este caso tendrías que nombrarlas pedido y respuesta... datos
No me gusta el const, prefiero var.
No es necesario usar await y async a no ser que necesites varios hilos y múltiples cargas al mismo tiempo, de lo contrario es ineficiente.

Tu publicación es más un comentario que una respuesta. const y var no son equivalentes, por lo que no hay nada que preferir, en la pregunta están bien utilizados.  Por otro lado await/async, son formas de manejar las promesas, la otra es utilizando las funciones then/catch/finally, ambas formas son equivalentes, entonces no puedes utilizar un fetch que devuelve una promesa sin alguno de los 2 métodos, por lo que es completamente necesario e imprescindible su uso. Lo ineficiente sería hacer un fetch síncrono (si es que se pudiera) y bloquear el hilo principal

@Yussef Vivir en la calle y vivir en una casa tampoco son equivalentes, pero prefiero vivir en una casa.

let y var podrían ser llamados equivalentes (si nos olvidamos del scope, que no es poca cosa), pero nunca lo serán con const, es que son opuestos!  uno  es VARiable y el otro es CONSTante, entonces no hay lugar a preferencias, se utilizan cuando se necesite el caso.

@Yussef A mí no me gusta que algo sea constante, prefiero que todo se pueda cambiar, por eso lo digo. Imagina que te pintan tu casa de color rojo, un día te cansas, y no vas a poder pintarlo de otro color por culpa de un const.

Es que cuando la norma de urbanismo dicta que tu casa debe ser roja, es necesario utilizar const, por otro lado, si no existe esa norma utilizas var o let. Existen muy buenas razones para utilizar const que van desde evitar errores como usar el mismo nombre en una variable, sin recordar que más arriba ya la estas utilizando, hasta aspectos de seguridad, por ejemplo yo leo un periódico donde ponen demasiada publicidad y les reescribo las funciones desde la consola, esto no lo podría hacer si las funciones fueran const

@Yussef Entiendo, a mí no me gusta ni la seguridad ni las normas.
